# PYMSSQL - error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

Pessoal estou enfrentando um problema com a biblioteca do pymssql, sempre que tento fazer uma conexão ele apresenta o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a str de conexão:

```
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=teste;uid=sa;pwd=TesteCon@123")

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("Select * from test")
for row in cur:
    print row.nome + ',' + row.email + ',' + row.id
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um alerta de desuso (DeprecationWarning) do `collections`, esse alerta começou agora na versão 3.7 do Python.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#id3

---

collections

In `Python 3.8`, the abstract base classes in `collections.abc` will no longer be exposed in the regular collections module. This will help create a clearer distinction between the concrete classes and the abstract base classes. (Contributed by Serhiy Storchaka in bpo-25988.)

---

A partir da versão 3.8 a forma antiga de importar o modulo não será mais suportada.

Se não é você que está fazendo esse `import` o mantenedor do conector deverá atualizar o mesmo em algum momento.

Com relação ao `pymssql` o mesmo é listado como uma opção de conector, contudo o site oficial do SQL server diz:

---

Há vários drivers SQL do Python disponíveis. No entanto, a Microsoft coloca seus esforços de teste e sua confiança em `pyodbc` driver.

---

Como a Microsoft testa e ajuda no desenvolvimento do `pyodbc` acredito que ele seja uma opção mais interessante que o `pymssql`.

A sua string de conexão está diferente na parte do **driver** também:

**pyodbc**

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

**pymssql**

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pymssql?view=sql-server-2017

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='yourserver.database.windows.net', user='yourusername@yourserver', password='yourpassword', database='AdventureWorks')
```

Comment: Recorri ao eu do pyodbc e foi com sucesso obrigado!